# Reshaping an Gym array for TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tflearn, openai-gym

I am learning how to use Gym environments to train deep learning models built with TFLearn.

At the moment my array of observations has the following shape: `(210, 160, 3)`

Any recommendations on what is the best way to reshape this array so it can be used in a TensorFlow classification model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way (as described in the [DQN paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf) by DeepMing) would be:

1. Convert it to the Gray-Scale,so you end-up with (210,160). Here you better check that no useful information is lost, in some games this can happen. (For example a ball became the same 'color' as a background). Here you can use something like:

   `processed = np.mean(frame,2,keepdims = False)`
2. Downsample to (110,84). Here you can use OpenCV or any other convenient library:

   `resized = cv2.resize(processed, (110,84),interpolation = cv2.CV_INTER_LINEAR)`
3. Crop central part of the screen (84,84)

   `result = resized[13:97]`

Although, this was described in the DeepMind paper, you can use more convenient, but still effective procedures, like:

1. Convert to gray scale:

   `processed = np.mean(frame,2,keepdims = False)`
2. Crop central part:

   `cropped = processed[35:195]`
3. Downsample by factor of 2 and get (80,80) image:

   `result = cropped[::2,::2]`

Similar approach was used by Andrej Karpathy in his [blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/)

You also can use other dimension sizes, convert to a binary image instead of gray-scale or anything that works better for your application.

Once you have processed the image you can feed it to a convolutional network or flatten to a 1-D array and feed to a fully-connected network.

It's also useful to use a stack of several frames (usually 4) as a network input, together with skip-frames (after taking a frame you skip next 3 frames) as they usually do not contain much useful information.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check the blog and paper!

Comment: Why are you cropping the central part and know that you need exactly `[35:195]`

Comment: @SebM it was used by Karpathy in his blog, but you can use different region which works better for you or do not crop at all just downsample. The idea is that in many games top and bottom regions do not contain useful information and main action happens closer to the center. Because of that you always should check processed output before training the image, to make sure you haven't lost any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Gym itself has an `AtariPreprocessing` wrapper that you can use to preprocess the Atari environment. I believe the wrapper does something similar to what is done in the DQN paper asakryukin mentioned.

You can use it like this:

```py
import gym
from gym.wrappers import AtariPreprocessing

env = gym.make('Pong-v0')
env = AtariPreprocessing(env, frame_skip=1)
```

More information about the wrapper can be found [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/0.17.3/gym/wrappers/atari_preprocessing.py).